# How to test for a bad expression in python for infix

Tags: python

```
def main1(expr):
    if expr(eval) raise ValueError:
        raise ValueError("Not a correct expression")

main1((8+3)*(5-6)))
```

So, I have the parameters this: (8+3)*(5-6))

However, I purposely put another parenthesis on this, making this infix expression invalid.

Is there a way to do this in my code, where it tries to evaluate it, and if it runs a error, raise a Value error stating that it is not a valid input?

Comment: It would just raise a SyntaxError

Comment: Shouldn't the call to main1 pass the expression as a string: `main1("(8+3)*(5-6))")`?

Comment: 1) it should be `eval(expr)`,  yours is the other way around.
2) your parameter needs to be a string.
3) that's not how you check for exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a try - catch.

Though to be honest there is no good reason to use this. The error that is raised is already a syntax error, which is the error that the user would expect if the syntax is wrong.

A better way of doing this may be:

```
def main1(expr):
    try:
        eval(expr)
    except SyntaxError:
        #logger.error("This is not a correct expression")
        print("This is not a correct expression")
        raise
```

Or if you are set on this decision, this should do what you want.

```
def main1(expr):
    try:
        eval(expr)
    except SyntaxError:
        raise ValueError("Not a correct expression")

main1("(8+3)*(5-6))")
```

Comment: using a try catch for syntax errors is just... no. I would not encourage this.